# SAS assign group and accumulate

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which have columns Event and Time. I need to create columns Group and Cumulative. What I need to measure is the duration of the Event 'Event1_Stop' until an 'Event1_Start' appears. Last group should sum the time meaning that the stop is ongoing and no start for the event has entered.
My data sample is:

```
data have;
length Event $15;
input Event $ Time;
datalines;
Event3_Start 0.2
Event2_Start 0.4
Event2_Stop 0.2 
Event1_Stop 0.2
Event3_Start 0
Event4_Start 0.5
Event3_Stop 0.2
Event1_Start 0
Event4_Stop 0
Event4_Stop 0
Event1_Stop 0.3
Event3_Start 0.3
Event1_Start 0
Event3_Start 0.4
Event3_Stop 0
Event1_Stop 0.2
Event3_Start 0.2
Event2_Start 0.4
run;
```

The result dataset that I need to obtain is:

```
data have;
length Event $15;
input Event $ Time Group Cumulative;
datalines;
Event3_Start 0.2 0 0
Event2_Start 0.4 0 0
Event2_Stop  0.2 0 0 
Event1_Stop  0.2 1 0.9
Event3_Start 0 1 0
Event4_Start 0.5 1 0
Event3_Stop  0.2 1 0
Event1_Start 0 0 0
Event4_Stop  0 0 0
Event4_Stop  0 0 0
Event1_Stop  0.3 2 0.6
Event3_Start 0.3 2 0
Event1_Start 0 0 0
Event3_Start 0.4 0 0
Event3_Stop  0 0 0
Event1_Stop  0.2 3 0.8
Event3_Start 0.2 3 0
Event2_Start 0.4 3 0
run;
```

Thanks for your suggestions.
Regards.

Comment: What does your desired result look like given this data?

Comment: Hi @draycut, I update the post. Sorry that was my result data. Initial data is only first two columns.

Comment: Thanks. And you want to keep the original order of observations, correct?

Comment: @draycut, yes please, I need to maintain the same order in the observations.

Comment: How does the 0.9 appear in cumulative?

Comment: 0.9 is the sum time of all the events between 'Event1_Stop' and the next 'Event1_Start'. It is the group = 1.
    Event1_Stop  0.2 
    Event3_Start 0 
    Event4_Start 0.5 
    Event3_Stop  0.2

Comment: Ok. I don't understand the group variable here though?

Comment: When is group = 0 / >0 here? Why is group = 1 in obs 4 and 0 in obs 3?

Comment: Hi @draycut, sorry if my explanation was not clear. I want to know the duration of Event1_Stop (only this event). The duration is defined as the cumulative sum of all the event's time between an Event1_Stop and Event1_Start. Therefore, when Event1_Stop appears I create a group with all the observations next to it until an 'Event1_Start' appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mkeintz on SAS forum for the solution:

```
data stop_to_start (keep=group cumulative);
set have end=end_of_have;
group+(event='Event1_Stop');
if event='Event1_Stop' then cumulative=0;
cumulative+time;
if end_of_have or event='Event1_Start' ;
run;

data want;
set have;
if _n_=1 or event='Event1_Start' then group=0;
cumulative=0;
if event='Event1_Stop' then set stop_to_start;
run;
```